# Trouble creating auth string using PHP HMAC SHA1 and Base64

Tags: php, laravel, hash, base64, sha1

So I am working with this API and using Laravel, and I am trying to build an auth string. This is the documentation I was given, but I am having a little trouble as this is something relatively new to me.

Here are the auth instructions:

> The authentication parameter is a string and it can calculated by the
>   caller or the caller can choose to save this value as a parameter
>   together with connection ID and API key.
>
> The authentication is a base64 string of a HMAC SHA1 hash. This is
>   computed by using the binary of API Key in in
>
> ########################## format in all lower case and UTF8 encoding as the key and computer HMAC SHA1 hash on the binary of
>
> Connection ID in ################################ format in all lower
>   case and UTF8 encoding.
>
> The result binary hash is then base64 encoded and the text result is
>   what should be passed as the authentication parameter. In C# the code
>   to calculate the authentication may look like:
>
> ```
> HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(
>   UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey.ToString("N").ToLower())
> );
> string authentication = Convert.ToBase64String(
>   hmac.ComputeHash(
>     UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(connectionId.ToString("N").ToLower())
>   )
> );
> ```
>
> As an example the following credentials:
>
> Connection ID: `5fecbc200f0e4a7cbf41040e11047e56`
>
> API Key: `2de51c4fd0f04b9fabeb95225e87da70`
>
> Should result in a computed authentication value of
>   `m5/Vc1RzhUETQvEtx/JdIglQpTg=`

So what i have been trying is:

```
$a = strtolower('5fecbc200f0e4a7cbf41040e11047e56');
$b = strtolower('2de51c4fd0f04b9fabeb95225e87da70');
$z = hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode(decbin($b)), utf8_encode(decbin($a)), true);
dd(base64_encode($z));
```

Which outputs `QjG3kzUs7U1UukNd++3t24pBWNk=`

I have tried a few more variations, but I am just lost on this one. First time really decoding or encoding anything. Would greatly appreciate any tips, ideas, or snippets that can help me figure this out. Already spent a few hours on this and it's bugging me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** Get rid of [`utf8_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and just generally don't use it. It assumes that the input string is ISO-88591-1 and if it is *anything else* it will silently corrupt the data. This function has an incredibly misleading name, and I would go as far as to suggest that no one should ever use it or the corresponding `utf8_decode()` which will break your data in the same manner, but reversed.

If you need to convert string encodings in PHP use something that *explicitly* defines the input *and* output encodings, eg: [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). [you still don't need it for this]

**Second:** Whatever you think [`decbin()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) does, you're incorrect. It converts an integer into a literal, capital-S String composed of `0` and `1` *characters*.

**Third:** PHP strings have *no inherent encoding* and are roughly equivalent to byte arrays if you twisted my arm for a description. The bytes you put into them are the bytes you get out of them.

**Fourth:** I'm not exactly a C# expert [or intermediate, or even *beginner*] but that example code is horrendous. What even is the significance of the `N` in `connectionId.ToString("N")`? I can't find any documentation about this.

Start simple, use meaningful variable names, build up, and *read the docs*.

```
$connectionID = strtolower('5fecbc200f0e4a7cbf41040e11047e56');
$apiKey       = strtolower('2de51c4fd0f04b9fabeb95225e87da70');
$hash         = hash_hmac("sha1", $connectionID, $apiKey, true);
var_dump(base64_encode($hash));
```

Output:

```
string(28) "m5/Vc1RzhUETQvEtx/JdIglQpTg="
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I can't believe I basically oofed myself. Thanks for the input. Yeah, it was written terribly and clearly I was overthinking/overreading it.